# Terraform, OCI: oci_audit_configuration timing out

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Terraform times out on creation of a resource `oci_audit_configuration` (meant as a dependency for `oci_mysql_mysql_db_system`). I cannot understand why.

mysql.tf:

```
resource "oci_audit_configuration" "configuration" {
    compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
    retention_period_days = var.configuration_retention_period_days
}
```

resulting in:

```
Error: Timed out waiting for configuration to reach specified condition.

  on ../modules/mysql/mysql.tf line 1, in resource "oci_audit_configuration" "configuration":
   1: resource "oci_audit_configuration" "configuration" {
```

Comment: Would you mind updating the question with the `mysql.tf` code and omit anything sensitive?

Comment: The `mysql.tf` has been reduced just to the single resource: `oci_audit_configuration`. This has been highlighted now in the question itself

Comment: Thanks. Well, I took a look at the resource definition itself on Terraform Registry, but I cannot find any timers that would allow for setting how long to wait for the change to be completed. I am not that familiar with Oracle Cloud, but looking at what MySQL resource requires, could it be that some parts of that configuration aren't passing the audit?

Comment: In the code above, at this stage I'm creating just the `oci_audit_configuration`, not yet the database itself

Comment: I suspect it's timing-out due to the lack of the privileges on my account. I've also found out that the `oci_mysql_mysql_db_system.configuration_id` parameter became optional somewhere between the OCI provider `v3.97.0` and `v4.7.0` and I can create the `oci_mysql_mysql_db_system` resource without the explicit dependency on `oci_audit_configuration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `configuration_id` of `oci_mysql_mysql_db_system` is not `oci_audit_configuration`.
You can view the example how to create `oci_mysql_mysql_db_system` here:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci/blob/master/examples/mysql/main.tf#L58

the `configuration_id` is something like this:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci/blob/master/examples/mysql/main.tf#L98